Sharepoint List - Dynamic selection in lookup column based upon user
I have two Sharepoint Lists shared across multiple people:
List A

User
Priority

List B

User
Action
Lookup pointing to [Priority in Table A]

How do I ensure (I assume using Power Automate) that when the user updates / adds a row to List B, that they can only select from 'their' rows in List A

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
